# Matlab: Iterating over large groups of stored data

Tags: matlab

I am looking at storing my multiple variables into the one array or cell matrix.
The data I currently have is
    seaLevel <339x1 double>
    tideLevel <201x1 double>
    height <55x1 double>

I want to have all of these in the one class so I can iterate through each group.

So varGroup will contain all three of the above variables with their name

Hope someone can help

Answer (score 0):

Just define structure in matlab such as

z = struct('seaLevel', zeros(1,339),
'tideLevel', zeros(1,201),
'height', zeros(1,55));

And you can create an array of structure as well 
data(n) = z;

Comment: How would I go about putting the data in that struct now?
So I have 339 values that need to go into the first entry. is there a quick method?

Comment: There are many ways to put the data in the struct, you can put the data while declaring it
z = struct('seaLevel', data(1x339), 'tideLevel', data(1x201), 'height', data(1x55));
or
z = struct('seaLevel', zeros(1,339), 'tideLevel', zeros(1,201), 'height', zeros(1,55));
z.seaLevel = data(1x339) 
z.tideLevel = data(1x201) ;

Comment: Okay, I have that all worked out.
But my main question was to have the ability to be bale to iterate through them. With that I will not be able to.
I can not access each one within a simple for loop

Answer (score 0):

To expand on [the other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32131992/matlab-iterating-over-large-groups-of-stored-data/32132254#32132254) and your comments, you can use a `struct` and still be able to access all of them within a loop by utilizing [`fieldnames`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fieldnames.html) and [dynamic field references](http://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2005/12/13/use-dynamic-field-references/). Depending on what you're doing with the variables, [`structfun`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/structfun.html) might also be an option.

For example:

```
% Dummy data!
seaLevel = rand(339, 1);
tideLevel = rand(201, 1);
height = rand(55, 1);

% Generate our data structure
mydata_struct = struct( ...
    'seaLevel', seaLevel, ...
    'tideLevel', tideLevel, ...
    'height', height ...
    );

datafields = fieldnames(mydata_struct);
nvariables = length(datafields);

for ii = 1:nvariables
    fprintf('Looping over ''%s'' data, %u data entries\n', datafields{ii}, length(mydata_struct.(datafields{ii})))
end
```

Which prints the following to the console:

```
Looping over 'seaLevel' data, 339 data entries
Looping over 'tideLevel' data, 201 data entries
Looping over 'height' data, 55 data entries
```

As you can see, you can loop over all of your data with a simple loop.

Alternatively, you can utilize a cell array:

```
% Dummy data!
seaLevel = rand(339, 1);
tideLevel = rand(201, 1);
height = rand(55, 1);

% Generate a cell array
mydata_cell = {seaLevel, tideLevel, height};
nvariables = length(mydata_cell);

for ii = 1:nvariables
    fprintf('Looping over data column %u, %u data entries\n', ii, length(mydata_cell{ii}))
end
```

Which prints the following to the console:

```
Looping over data column 1, 339 data entries
Looping over data column 2, 201 data entries
Looping over data column 3, 55 data entries
```

A cell array is slightly simpler, though you lose the ability to reference your data by name like you can with the `struct` array above. Both approaches allow you to store and access dissimilar data in the same array.